# Missing SCNMaterials array for SCNGeometry when reading Collada (.dae) file

Tags: ios, scenekit, collada

I am loading a mesh that was created using blender.  In the collada file there are 4 materials specified against the library-assets.  Then there is one geometry that has 4 polylists, each using one of these materials, that are referenced by name.   When I load in the mesh the SCNSource class has all the materials in it.  The SCNGeometry however has 4 Geometry elements (SCNGeometryElement), but it has no materials.  So there is a missing linkage , as now I can't get to the right material from the SCNGeometryElement.  Ideally the SCNGeometry element should have carried the material name which it does not; or the expected is that there should be 4 corresponding materials one for each SCNGeometryElement in the SCNGeometry.materials array.  However the array is empty.  So I am unable to make the correlation of the polylist to its index.  Other than manually reading the .dae file for myself and tying up the loose ends are there any other options to recover the lost information?

```
SCNSource
   [ (NSArray *)[scnSceneSource identifiersOfEntriesWithClass:[ SCNMaterial class ]] description ]
   (has 4 materials)
   SCNGeometry
      (has no materials)
      (has 4 SCNGeometry elements)
```

Glad for any help on this!

Comment: do you happen to have a *simple* Collada file that shows the issue?

Comment: [link](http://pastebin.com/qaz3VMfB) has a simple collada file that shows this problem. Its a cube with 5 faces having one material and a single face having a second material.